# SUA missing from "windows features"

Tags: windows-7, sua

The official instructions for installing the windows Subsystem for Unix-based Applications list two steps:

1. Open the "Turn Windows features on or off" window and turn on "Subsystem for Unix-based Applications."
2. Download and install the USA Utilities and SDK.

I'm stuck on step 1. The windows features dialog box on my Windows 7 Pro x64 system doesn't list SUA at all! None of the official or third-party instructions I've found address this possibility.

Here's a screenshot showing on the left, an image from the [installation tutorial video](http://www.suacommunity.com/SUA.aspx), and on the right, my own system. Notice no "subsystem" on the right.

[image]

If all else fails I could use Cygwin, but I wanted to try out this alternative.

Comment: I have it here on my Ultimate machine.  Perhaps it's Ultimate-only?

Comment: ...oh, yeah, it is.  Answer added.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This is only supported in Ultimate.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7_editions)  Sorry!

Comment: Yep. Seems this detail is overlooked in some of the the docs from both Microsoft and the community. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

More specifically, [Utilities and SDK for Subsystem for UNIX-based Applications in Microsoft Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=2391)

Lists the following as system requirements:
`Windows 7 Enterprise, Windows 7 Ultimate, Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit, Windows Server 2008 R2`

Which is sad, as Professional could benefit from NFS server `('mount' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.)`