# How to access NFS share from Windows 7 pro?

Tags: windows-7, nfs

Everywhere I see Windows and NFS, there is a mention of some kind of [subsystem of unix apps](https://superuser.com/questions/212864/sua-missing-from-windows-features/977655#977655) or something like this, but apparently it's not in Windows 7 pro.

So the question is: what can I do to get access to NFS share from Windows 7 Pro? What to download, from where? Is there any commercial application, or is it just some free software installation?

Comment: Although there are ways to mount NFS shares on Windows (and I see some good answers on that below) the more common approach is to have the server provide SMB shares instead of or in addition to NFS shares. This is done by running [Samba](http://www.samba.org/) on the file server. Many Linux distros come with Samba and integrate it into their file management GUI.

Answer (score 14):

I came in late, but here is a real solution: (opensource)

Was researching the same thing for win7 pro and found this:
http://www.trevorpott.com/?p=385

> The University of Michigan NFS v 4.1 client. This is the exact same
>   client for NFS 4.1 that Microsoft included in Windows 8.  (Indeed,
>   Microsoft funded its development.)  It is located here.  However, it
>   does take a little bit of knowledge to install.  I have found it
>   easily scriptable for installs on a mass scale, and certainly not a
>   problem for installs on my home machine.
>   download here: http://www.citi.umich.edu/projects/nfsv4/windows/readme.html#install

Comment: The git URL for the source code no longer works, and perusing through the directory structure got me nothing. Here is the one hosted on github: https://github.com/kofemann/ms-nfs41-client.git

Comment: This works but only supports NFSv4

Comment: The University of Michigan NFS v 4.1 client binaries (as well as source code) can be downloaded from http://www.citi.umich.edu/projects/nfsv4/windows/120612/. No need to compile from source unless you have special requirements.

Answer (score 3):

I was in the same boat. There's a 3rd party tool called [nfsAxe](http://www.labf.com/nfsaxe/index.html), though it's shareware. So far I've only found that, or upgrade to Enterprise or Ultimate.

Answer (score 3):

I changed version from Professional to Enterprise in registry and I was able to install "Services for NFS" from Programs and Features.

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion]
>
> "EditionID"="Enterprise"
>
> "ProductName"="Windows 7 Enterprise"

Comment: I changed the 2 fields and restarted, but the "Services for NFS" option doesn't show up in "Turn features on or off" dialog. How'd you get it to work?

Comment: This did not work for me either.

Answer (score 2):

To install NFS abilities in Win7 (verified on a Win 7 Enterprise x64 install):

Control Panel > Programs and Features > Turn Windows features on or off (upper left corner) > Check 'Services for NFS' in the listing > Ok each dialog

[image]

Comment: windows pro doesn't have "services for NFS" in windows features.

Comment: Maybe a Ultimate/Enterprise only feature.  Seems from a quick web search that others With Windows 7 Pro upgrade to Ultimate or find a 3rd party tool.

Comment: I have zero knowledge of Windows, it's definitely not my OS of choice. Any idea what 3rd party tools are available? Any good? Any worth recommending?

Comment: I just know how to get the component installed, never used it myself.

Comment: It is definitely not available, in any form, on Win 7 Pro.  You can't download or install anything from Microsoft, or do anything in Control Panel which will allow Win 7 Pro (or below) to use NFS client for Windows.  It is available in Enterprise and Ultimate.

Comment: available in Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate

Answer (score 0):

You used to need Unix Services for Windows, but it looks like you don't in 7 according to this. Not conclusive because I don't use 7, but looks like optional service that needs to be loaded.
http://sagehacks.wordpress.com/2009/01/21/howto-mount-nfs-shares-under-windows-7/

Comment: saw this page too, but in my windows 7, i was not able to find "Add/Remove Software wizard in the Control Panel."

Comment: I'll try one more blind stab, does the windows 7 control panel have a "classic view". Or did you check this out? http://gizmodo.com/#!5138189/win-7-tip-where-the-hell-is-addremove-programs  or  http://www.netomatix.com/post/2009/08/09/Add-remove-programs-in-Windows-7.aspx

Comment: Gizmodo.com link just shows me main page (redirected to gizmodo.pl for some reason). netomatix writes about removing programs. I don't see any "classic view" option/link.

Comment: This link at Microsoft http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/nfs-client-for-windows-7/42aae25d-d077-4ff9-abdf-7314a589c46d contains a link (down a ways) to download the services http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=dc03485b-629b-49a6-b5ef-18617d1a9804&displaylang=en  Though there is also some discussion farther down that it doesn't work for some people??? Very strange differences between versions.

Comment: @Dennis: tested it. As one of commenter there stated, it requires "UNIX services" which are not part of Windows 7 Pro.

Comment: I'm working on this because it may affect what version I get if I ever upgrade on those computers where I'm forced to use MS products. And now for what appears to be some fairly poorly documented bad news. You have to love windows 7 coming in so many helpful versions. (sorry that is purely editorial) http://superuser.com/questions/212864/sua-missing-from-windows-features

Answer (score 0):

[HOW TO: Share Windows Folders by Using Server for NFS:](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324089)

> You can use Server for NFS to make Windows resources available to UNIX
>   and Linux clients by using the NFS protocol. You can use either
>   Windows Explorer or the Nfsshare.exe command line utility to share the
>   folder.
>
> **To share a folder by using Nfsshare.exe:**
>
> 1. Log on to the Windows-based server by using an administrative level account.
> 2. Click Start, click Run, type cmd, and then click OK.
> 3. Type the following command, and then press ENTER to share a folder to NFS clients > and  to allow anonymous access:
>
>    nfsshare -o anon=yes share_name=drive:path
> 4. Type the following command, and then press ENTER to delete an NFS share:
>
>    nfsshare share_name /delete
> 5. Type: nfsshare /?, and then press ENTER to display the parameters that you can use with Nfsshare.
>
> **To share a folder by using Windows Explorer:**
>
> 1. Log on to the Windows-based server by using an administrative level account.
> 2. Start Windows Explorer.
> 3. Right-click the folder that you want to share, and then click Sharing.
> 4. Click the NFS Sharing tab, and then click Share this folder.
> 5. Configure the appropriate settings, and then click OK.NOTE: Microsoft recommends that you install at least one User Name Mapping
>      service on your network to map UNIX and Windows user names to each
>      other.

Comment: One-link answers are frowned upon here. Please extend your answer to include some details about the procedure instead of just linking somewhere.