# How to permanently mount an NFS share under Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, nfs

If I have an OpenWrt router with a 1,5TB HDD on it that's exported via NFS3, then how can I permanently mount it on an NFS share under Windows 7? (they're on the same subnet.)

Comment: Related: [How to access NFS share from Windows 7 pro?](http://superuser.com/questions/254321/how-to-access-nfs-share-from-windows-7-pro)

Comment: Alternatively, share the disk using [Samba](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/cifs.server)?

Comment: owrt router too slow for samba, only 133mhz cpu, only nfs :) :(